# How to remove Wordpress icon with CSS for not login users in the upper left corner

Tags: css, wordpress

How to remove Wordpress icon with CSS for not login users in the upper left corner.
Is this possible with css or do I need to go with php?

You can see it on my page http://virtual-forms.com

Edit: added screenshot:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hXDD.png)

Comment: As a "not logged in user" I can't see the WordPress logo on your site.  Usually the logo only shows when you are logged in, so is this not already working how you want?

Comment: @bert thank you for your comment. No the issue is not resolved. I have added a screenshot where it is shown how it is displayed on my end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a file with name like `removeicon.php` and put it in `wp-content/plugins/` folder, go to your wp dashboard, plugins and activate it(plugin) and your unwanted icon will disappear for none logged in users:

```
<?php
/* 
Plugin Name: remove icon
*/
function remove_icon_css() {
    echo 
    '<style>
        #wp-admin-bar-wp-logo{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>';
}
function remove_icon_code(){
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        add_action('wp_head', 'remove_icon_css');
    }
}
add_action('wp', 'remove_icon_code');
```

---

you can also put this code on your `/wp-content/themes/{theme-name}/functions.php` or `child-theme/functions.php`
if you want to know about `child-themes` and `functions.php` read [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/01/create-customize-wordpress-child-theme/)

Comment: thank you for your solution, but I wanted to skip this route (creating a child theme......).

Comment: child-theme is optional, put it in your theme functions.php

Comment: @davor.geci please read the answer again, and your problem will be solved.